# Flutter FireStore Create, Read and Update Array with a Map Object

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Fairly new to Flutter and FireStore, I'm having trouble finding examples or explanations on how to add Maps to an Array (specifically, Creating the initial Array with a Map, then Reading then Adding more Maps to the collection of the Notes Array).

I have an Event Class for scheduling events and that is working very well. What I'm trying to add is a "Notes" field that would allow an some Administrator to add Notes on one day then come back and add to that Event another set of notes as things change. I don't want to "overwrite" the previous Notes, just keep adding more Notes to the Array of notes.

Specific questions:

1. How do I Create the "Array" when adding the entry into FireStore using Flutter?
2. How do I Read the data in the "Array" when it's coming back as a set of "Map fields" in Flutter?
3. How do I just Add to the Array with a new Note? (I think this needs FieldValue.arrayUnion([someMap]) but I'm not certain as this appears to avoid any overwriting.

The page section here shows writing it out but little else: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types

Below is an example of the FireStore structure I'm trying to create.
[image]

Has anyone done this before and do you have some direction you can provide? The Firebase documentation in this space is thin...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. To create an new document with array in firestore:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('path/to/collection').add(
  { 'notesArray': [
    {'date': 'sometime', 'notes': 'somenotes', 'user': 'someuser'}
  ]},
  SetOptions(merge: true),
);
// or
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('path/to/collection').add(
  { 'notesArray': []}, // for an empty array
  SetOptions(merge: true),
);
```

2. To read the data:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('company').get().then((value) {
  final doc = value.data()!;
  print(doc['lname']); // should print Gethsemane
  print(doc['notesArray'] as List); // should print notes array
  final notes = doc['notesArray'] as List;
  for (final note in notes) {
    print(note['date']);
    print(note['notes']);
    print(note['user']);
  }
  // or
  for (int i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    print(notes[i]['date']);
  }
});
```

3. Add new data to notes array. Simply use [FieldValue.arrayUnion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

E.g

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('path/to/doc').set(
  {
    'notesArray': FieldValue.arrayUnion([
      {'date': 'sometime', 'notes': 'somenotes', 'user': 'someuser'}
    ]),
  },
  SetOptions(merge: true),
);
// I used set method along with setOptions in order not to 
// override other fields (e.g modifiedBy field)
```

Keep in mind that if your array is going to be very large, it is better to store the notes as a `subcollection`.

**##EDIT##**

If you want to update a nested array, you can use the dot notation.

```
class SchedulerEvents {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>>? notes;
  SchedulerEvents({required this.notes});
}

// lets assume we have data like this that we want to update
final data = SchedulerEvents(
  notes: [
    {'date': 'sometime', 'notes': 'somenotes', 'user': 'someuser'},
  ],
);
FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('path/to/doc').set(
  {
    'schedulerEvents.notes': FieldValue.arrayUnion([data.notes![0]]),
    // or
    'schedulerEvents.notes': FieldValue.arrayUnion(data.notes![0]),
    // 'schedulerEvents.lname: 'test', // to update other fields
  },
  SetOptions(merge: true),
);
// we used dot notation to update fields here.
```

Comment: Thank you @peter-obiechina, I'll give these a try and see if I can get the notesArray to work!

Comment: Thanks again Peter. The solution is VERY close right now but for the update, it appears that "FieldValue.arrayUnion" will ONLY take a string value for the field to update. In this case I have a custom object called "SchedulerEvents" with a field called "notes". Notes is a nullable List of type Map like so: "List<Map<String, dynamic>>? notes". When I try to invoke "FieldValue.arrayUnion" it complains that "The argument type 'FieldValue' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>?'" - have you run into something like this before?

Comment: I think so, but let me be sure I understand you. You want to add an `Array` to a field named 'notes' in an object named 'SchedulerEvents'? You can use the dot notation. I will update my answer (check the bottom part labelled edit). And `FieldValue.arrayUnion` can accept `Map` and `List<Map>` as shown in the Edit answer.

Comment: Thanks Peter! I've started a specific thread on this specific issue at the link below. The issue seems to be that the FieldValue.arrayUnion function will ONLY accept a string value for the field to point to. My testing seems to show that a pre-defined field doesn't work well? I've also included the entire code for 'SchedulerEvents': https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73651218/use-fieldvalue-arrayunion-in-flutter-with-cloud-firestore

Comment: Great work Peter! Thanks Again!